# Can somebody give me some hints why this answer has been deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers

Bill the Lizard deleted my answer at [Billing API v3 IabHelper NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456434/billing-api-v3-iabhelper-nullpointerexception/18040694#18040694) .

Can somebody give me some hints why this answer has been deleted? Unfortunately I posted the sad truth. Any app using the latest version of Googles "In App Billing" tool IabHelper.java will experience numerous crashes. The code has at 5-10 severe bugs. I reported the problem but nothing happened so far.

Comment: Did you try asking Bill directly through email or something?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I think by "reported the problem" he means he reported the bug that post is about, not Bill.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question at all. It just says "there are lots of problems with that software, don't use it." (I think it would have been fine as a comment)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Posting a meta question to ask for clarification/explaination on a moderator action is entirely appropriate (so long as it is phrased constructively.

Comment: @AlEverett If an action is taken by a specific user there's no reason *not* to reference the user. The user in question is visible anyway if you have sufficient rep.

Comment: In other news: hoo, boy; that post is a mess.  It looks like a really messy forum post, not a Q&A.

Comment: I don't get the point, you posted two answers.  One was "it is complete junk, don't bother", the other was "here's a simple patch to fix it".  Which one do you prefer to keep?

Comment: My patch is fixing one issue. But there are minimum 5 others. The code really is junk and I made sure I have the latest. The problem for any app developer is that now his app his crashing although in fact it is the official helper recommended by Google. I described the issues. Anyone digging in the code will find it.

Comment: In fact this is like asking the question: I have problems with Windows Backup giving me error 0x123,0x222 and sometimes 0x987. You now have 2 Options: 1.) Wasting much time by trying to fix each issue, and never succeed or 2.) accept the fact that windows backup is so crap, that the best advice is: Do not use it and look for another solution and save much time. What you guys are trying to tell me, is that SO can only Option 1. I think the user is more interested in solutions means 2.) than answers to any problem like in 1.)

Answer (score 12):

Because it's not an answer, it's commentary.

SO isn't an issue tracker for the code in question. Confirming issues, or reporting new ones, doesn't answer the question. Things-that-aren't-answers-but-given-as-answers *should* be deleted.

Comment: To embellish on Dave's answer a bit: Answers are reserved for posting information that *directly answers the question.*

Comment: But this is like the question: How do I get to the other side of the river? Answer: You cannot get to the other side because the ferry is closed. In your logic this very valuable answer would be deleted.

Comment: @tmanthey You asked why the answer was deleted, I told you-because it's not an answer. Commentary is for blogs, which you're welcome to write and post a link to in the comments. SO is *not* a discussion forum-that's not a value judgement on SO or your commentary, it's just what it is.